# Force an IFrame to load the mobile version of a website

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, user-agent

I need to load a mobile version of a website inside an iFrame of a webpage i'm building,
the URL is this

https://m.calcionapoli24.it/diretta/spalletti-napoli-spartak-mosca-conferenza-n495703.html

but there is an automatic redirect to the desktop version of URL

https://www.calcionapoli24.it/diretta/spalletti-napoli-spartak-mosca-conferenza-n495703.html

How can avoid the redirect? How can i force the IFrame to load the mobile version?

Change User-Agent? PHP Curl? Javascript AJAX?

the code is quite basic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        iframe {
    width: 750px;
    max-width: 750px;
    height: 1334px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-width: 0px;
    display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <iframe src="https://m.calcionapoli24.it/diretta/spalletti-napoli-spartak-mosca-conferenza-n495703.html"></iframe>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend a query parameter in the url ex `?from_frame=1`

Then catch this rule from an .htaccess file and make an .htaccess internal redirect to the mobile version of the website

Comment: Agamemnon i can't understand in which way a .htaccess file can have effect to an i

Comment: You should find the level where the problematic redirect occurs

Comment: when i set src attribute to Iframe the IFrame itself shows the desktop version of the URL of that external page

Comment: Where and why the redirect from m. to www happens?

Comment: i have added code to my question, it's really basic
inside the src attribute of IFrame there is the URL of the mobile version of that external page, when i see the HTML page on Chrome in the IFrame it shows the desktop version of the URL (without m.)